# Problem with shipping in Virtuemart

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

I want to set the shipping module in virtuemart. There is a problem in shipping..
 As of I know, Virtuemart calculates the whole weight of the products added to cart by an user and then displays a shipping rate corresponds to the weight and the country where the user is from. The shipping rates are set in the backend by me.

The problem arises in the checkout process is that if an user add products whose total weight is suppose 6pounds and the user is purchasing from UK, but the VM shows the wrong shipping rate say ranging from 0-5pounds (actually should display 6-10pounds or some thing inside that range) but the country is displaying correctly..this is wat I'm stuck with..

Otherwise I think there is some wrong configuration I did in Virtuemart. I'll summarize what I had done. I had set in the back-end shipping rates ranging from

```
say 0-5 pounds UK, 6-10 pounds UK, 11-15 pounds UK, 0-5 pounds US, 6-10 pounds US, 11-15 pounds US,0-5 pounds CN, 6-10 pounds CN, 11-15 pounds CN under a Custom Shipper Name.
```

I had also set Admin->Configuration->Shipping-> as "Standard Shipping module with individual configured carriers and rates. RECOMMENDED !" this only..All others are unchecked.

Please suggest a remedy for this...

Comment: Have you set weight for each individual product? You haven't mentioned this above.

Answer (score 0):

It can be a problem with the units of measurement. 6 pounds is about 2.7 kilograms. If the shipping module is using kilograms as the unit of measure, and specify a range 0 - 6, can take it from 0 to 6 kilograms.